# AngularJS otherwise function redirects me to wrong route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have routes difened like this:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/settings', { templateUrl: 'settingsTemplateURL', controller: settingsCtrl })
    .when('/profile', { templateUrl: 'profileTemplateURL', controller: profileCtrl })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/settings' });
```

I'm using my webb on adresses like this: localhost/testapp/#/settings or localhost/testapp/#/profile and etc...

And problem starts when I request address: localhost/testapp In this moment otherwise function redirects me on localhost/testapp#/settings where slash after 'testapp' is missing. This is difference between version of AngularJS, because this problem comes after updating AngularJS from version 1.0.7 to 1.2.13

Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks David

Answer (score 1):

the problem is `localhost`. 
try to use: `http://127.0.0.1/` instead of `localhost`

Also you might still have problems when the $.route is trying to recover the templates, sometimes is doesn't work because the correct headers are not sent, but that depends on your settings.

did it work?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works fine on production server with address like you wrote. But is there some workaround how to fix it on my local too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to get it to work in local host you have to call the routes remotely like this:

```
    $routeProvider.when('/home',      {   
             templateUrl: 'http://yoururl.com/model/app/whatever.php',       
             controller: 'Dashboard'      
    })
```

be sure to add trusted sources:

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self','http://yoururl.com/model/app/**']);
```

and to your php:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept');
```

And it works.

This is the only way it's ever going to work with `localhost`